# ax.plot_surface not giving colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make a 3d plot because wolfram can't handle the eq. But python also seems to have trouble. I basically used the surf plot example: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html and it doesn't work. Anybody any idea why?
[image]

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
x = y = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.25)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

z = (2*x**2 *(np.sqrt(x**2-4 * x+y**2+8)+ np.sqrt(x**2+4 * x+y**2+8))-x*(y**2-4)*
     (np.sqrt(x**2-4 * x+y**2+8)-np.sqrt(x**2+4 * x+y**2+8))-2*(y**2+4)+(np.sqrt(x**2-4 * x+y**2+8)+np.sqrt(x**2+4 * x+y**2+8))+x**3 *
     (np.sqrt(x**2+4 * x+y**2+8)-np.sqrt(x**2-4 * x+y**2+8)))/((x**2-4 * x+y**2+4) * np.sqrt(x**2-4 * x+y**2+8)*(x**2+4 * x+y**2+4)*np.sqrt(x**2+4 * x+y**2+8))

surf = ax.plot_surface(x,y,z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim(-0.1, 0.1)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that the `z` surface is very spiked shape, and in fact `z.max( ) = inf`. one thing you may do is to replace infinite values by the finite maximum value:

```
z[ np.isinf( z )] = z[ np.isfinite(z)].max( )
```

and that will give you the plot below. note that I have not set z-limits ( `ax.set_zlim` ), so that the whole shape is visible.

[image: spike]

if you are only interested in the portion of the plot which is between `[-.1, .1]`, you may cut-off `z` at those points by:

```
z[ z > .1 ] = .1
z[ z < -.1 ] = -.1
```

and you will get:

[image: surf]

Answer (score 1):

A couple things - first, your calculations will go faster if you assign common elements to variables. For example,

```
np.sqrt(x**2 - 4*x + y**2 + 8)
np.sqrt(x**2 + 4*x + y**2 + 8)
```

are used multiple times in your mega-`z` equation. Assign the results of those calculations to variables and then use the variables when building `z`. You'll be able to spot mistakes more easily, and you'll save CPU cycles:

```
a = np.sqrt(x**2 - 4*x + y**2 + 8)
b = np.sqrt(x**2 + 4*x + y**2 + 8)

c = (2*x**2 *(a + b)-x*(y**2 - 4) * (a - b)-2*(y**2+4)+(a + b)+x**3 * (b - a))
d = (x**2-4 * x+y**2+4) * a*(x**2+4 * x+y**2+4)*b

z = c / d
```

The reason your program isn't working is because you have a divide by zero error somewhere in your massive `z =` equation. I'll leave it to you to track it down, but one thing you may want to do is carefully examine your equation and make sure you have parentheses where appropriate.